# How do I map special paths in my home directory to a path on another drive?

Tags: windows-8.1

I just got a new computer (windows 8.1) and I have two drives.  The main C drive is an SSD and the D drive is a regular drive.  I want to move some of the less important data to the secondary drive, such as `Downloads`.

I know I can do it using `MKLINK` but I can't remove the `Downloads` folder as I get an `Access is denied` error, and I think that it may be a special folder anyway (a folder that may have some 'magic' attached to it).

Is there a clean way of doing this?  Does it have 'magic' attached to it?

Comment: On my box I just did a right click, properties, and moved the location (a browse dialog appears and lets you choose the drive, etc.).  It moved all the goodies for me...  Last I did that was W7, but I believe the option is still there in W8+.

Comment: @nerdwaller Awesome!  Didn't see that before.  Post it as an answer and I'll give you the cred. :)

Comment: Done, should've posted it there first.  But I don't have a W8 box around to test it on (which I like to do before posting an answer).  Glad it solves your problem!

Comment: @techie007, I'd say it's close, but not quite though.

Comment: @Adrian How is it different? You want to move a system-type folder(Downloads), and that's the same thing the other question is asking about (for the same reasons even).  The answer you accepted here is even [one of the answers](http://superuser.com/a/316483/23133) on the possible dupe. :)

Comment: @techie007, you're right.  I think I just didn't like the selected answer.  This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Migrated (and adjusted) from a comment*

On Windows 7, you can change the location and let Windows worry about moving everything and making the links as necessary.  On 7 it is `Right Click > Properties > Location Tab > Move`.

I am pretty confident that Windows 8+ maintained that option as smaller boot drives are increasingly common.

Comment: What did you mean by _Migrated (and adjusted) from a comment_?

Comment: @Adrian - It was a comment (under your question), you said "Post it as an answer and I'll give you the cred. :)". So I tweaked it (adjusted) and migrated it here, as an answer.